# Transit visa at Istanbul, Turkey

Tags: transit-visas, turkey, tours, istanbul, bangladeshi-citizens

I'm a Bangladeshi citizen, currently studying in Moscow, Russia. Willing to fly to Abu Dhabi by Turkish airlines and get a transit at Istanbul which will be more than 12 hours. I want to take the 'Tour Istanbul' package of Turkish Airlines. Now,

- What procedures should I go through? Do I need to get e-visa before flying, or can I collect it at the airport desk? What will be the cost in each case?
- And most importantly is there any condition for Bangladeshi ordinary passport holders?

Answer (score 1):

These are the requirements listed for Bangladeshi citizens on the Turkish [eVisa](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/apply/) website, as seen on 2019-01-18.

Visa Fee is listed as **USD 60**.

> - My passport covers the period that I will be staying in Turkey.
> - I am travelling for the purposes of tourism or business.
> - I have a valid Supporting Document (Valid visa OR valid residence permit from one of the Schengen Countries, USA, UK or Ireland). E-visas are not accepted as supporting documents.
> - I can prove that I hold a return ticket, hotel reservation and at least 50 $ per each day of my stay.
> - I confirm that I meet each and every one of the conditions listed above.

You can get the eVisa either from home or at the airport after you land, using the automated Kiosks. But you do have to fulfill all the requirements above. Without a valid visa for any of the countries listed above, unfortunately eVisa is not going to be granted.